# Python - Spyder Dataframe Float Format Variable Explorer with thousands separator

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, number-formatting, separator

I want to know if it's possible to change the Spyder DataFrame float format in the variable explorer to include the thousands separator? I am not talking about when you use print().format , that is for when you output your results, I am talking about the Format option when you click on a DataFrame in the variable exporer as shown here:
[DataFrame Spyder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaeEd.png)

The format is using the % convention and not the {}, so to have 2 decimals I need to write `%.2f` instead of `{:.2f}` . I am currently able to change it to either full integer with `%i` or a 2-decimal float with `%.2f`, but I want to know if it's possible to include the thousands separator. Essientially being able to reproduce something like `{:,.2f}` but with %.. I tried `%:,.2f`, `%0:,.2f` , and many other combinations with a comma but to no success. I've been looking but can't find anything addressing this, other solutions are using the pd.set_options method but this only works when you actually print out the dataframe.

Thank you!

Comment: did you find something ?

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: I'm afraid there is no solution as it only accepts the type field (after the %), using printf. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf